# How would I apply intermediate value theorem to this question?

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

The question is the following: "Suppose f : R → R is continuous and periodic with period 2a for some a > 0; that is,
f(x) = f(x + 2a) for all x ∈ R. Show there is some c ∈ [0, a] such that f(c) = f(c + a)."

The only way I see to do this question is to apply the intermediate value theorem, but I just don't know how to apply it to this question. I know that f(x) = f(x+2a). Therefore, if i can show that f(c+a) = f(c+2a) or f(c+a) - f(c+2a) = 0, I'd be done. But I just don't know where to go from there. I tried substituting x = a, getting f(2a) - f(3a), but I can't show that's less than, equal to, or greater than 0. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Define a function $g(x) = f(x+a) - f(x)$. If $g(0) = 0$, then you're done; if not, note that $g(a) = -g(0)$.

Comment: So should I split it up into cases?

Comment: Sure; the $g(0) = 0$ case is the trivial one, and the other case is the one where you still have something to do.

Comment: Also, I did a bad thing with that hint: I didn't explain the intuition behind it.

What led me to that hint was: you're trying to show that $f(c+a) = f(c)$ somewhere, or that $f(c+a) - f(c) = 0$. Since this did indeed feel like an IVT problem, the typical thing to do in this situation is define a function that looks like that and hope you can assert what you need somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how did u arrive to the conclusion that g(a) = -g(0)?

Comment: Note that $g(0) = f(a) - f(0)$, and that $g(a) = f(2a) - f(a)$; use the periodicity of $f$.